# Systemctl: Failed to start Node.js Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, systemctl

I've seen one other post about this problem and it didn't seem to work so I'm posting my issue that might be a little different. The code for my service is file is below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Application
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
Enviroment=NODE_ENV=production
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node helloworld.js

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the tutorial I am using:
https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/deploy-node-js-application-linux-server/
I am using a Raspberry Pi if that makes a difference

The error says:

```
helloworld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
helloworld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Node.js Application
```

Comment: Are both node and helloworld.js located in the /usr/bin/ ?

Comment: I have no idea. How would I check that?

Comment: `ls /usr/bin`  try this command and see if the file shows up

Comment: Node is but helloworld.js does not seem to be. How can I move helloworld.js to that directory?

Comment: does `ls` this command shows your file?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out by making a new file with nano with that directory. I tested it and does not seem to work still.

Comment: ok so the file is now in `/usr/bin/`?

Comment: yes it is in that folder

Comment: try this: `ExecStart= /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/helloworld.js`

Comment: It still is having the same error.

Comment: Although, above it says: helloworld.service: Started request repeated too quickly. and : helloworld.service Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: what's the exit code?

Comment: I don't know what that is. I don't think I have any.

Comment: please show the error message

Comment: Jul 17 00:53:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: helloworld.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jul 17 00:53:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: helloworld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 15.
Jul 17 00:53:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Node.js Application.
Jul 17 00:53:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: helloworld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 17 00:53:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: helloworld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 00:53:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Node.js Application.

Comment: \u25cf helloworld.service - Node.js Application
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/helloworld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-07-17 00:53:25 EDT; 21min ago
  Process: 9426 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node usr/bin/helloworld.js (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9426 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
(sorry this is the wrong way around, this one goes first)

Comment: The error code is 1, which means that there is something wrong with the code in `helloworld.js`

Comment: Ok, well the hellowold.js runs perfectly fine when running. I can both open the webpage and do curl with is